# Opacity script/backgroud image working in chrome not in IE 11

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a cross-browser compatibility problem.

[Here is a jsfiddle of my code.](http://jsfiddle.net/mT4y9/1/)

Essentially, the desired effect is for the squares to be opacity="0.5" onmouseout and opacity ="1" onmouseover. The squares, once clicked, redirect to a page.

The code works as desired on Chrome, but on IE 11 the background images doesn't show up. Also I noticed the opacity function for onmouseout/onmouseover doesn't work.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script>
            function bigImg(x) {
                x.style.opacity = "1";
            }

            function normalImg(x) {
                x.style.opacity = "0.5";
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            table.imagetable {
                font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
                font-size:11px;
                color:#FFFFFF;
                border-width: 3px;
                border-color: #FFFFFF;
                table-layout: fixed;
            }
            table.imagetable th {
                border-width: 3px;
                padding: 3px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: #FFFFFF;
                border-spacing: 3px;
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
            }
            table.imagetable td {
                border-width: 3px;
                padding: 3px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: #FFFFFF;
                border-spacing: 3px;
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
            }
            table.imagetable td:hover {
                cursor: pointer;
                cursor: hand;
            }
            #app1 {
                background-image: url("http://gprgeo@www.gprairborne.com/images/airborne/blue.png");
            }
            #app2 {
                background-image: url("http://gprgeo@www.gprairborne.com/images/airborne/blue2.png");
            }
            #app3 {
                background-image: url("http://gprgeo@www.gprairborne.com/images/airborne/blue3.png");
            }
            #app4 {
                background-image: url("http://gprgeo@www.gprairborne.com/images/airborne/blue4.png");
            }
            #app5 {
                background-image: url("http://gprgeo@www.gprairborne.com/images/airborne/blue5.png");
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <table class="imagetable">
        <tr>
            <td id="app1" onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" onClick="javascript:location.href='http://www.google.com';"></td>
            <td id="app2" onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" onClick="javascript:location.href='http://www.google.com';"></td>
            <td id="app3" onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" onClick="javascript:location.href='http://www.google.com';"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="app4" onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" onClick="javascript:location.href='http://www.google.com';"></td>
            <td id="app5" onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" onClick="javascript:location.href='http://www.google.com';"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</html>
```

EDIT:

Ok so everything is working properly now, the path to the images is blocked since they are provided from a website under construction and requires login. IE 11 had a problem with such even when logged in on the browser, chrome didn't. See the below jsfiddle for working desired effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/nP7pd/4/

Comment: Opacity values aren't strings - have you tried using actual numbers?

Comment: @AlienWebguy , hey that's true, I just changed it but still it doesn't show up on IE 11..